# Arrays manipulation with respect to range of values

Tags: java, arrays

I have this requirement that I need to set the values in a byte array of size 20MB.

I'm looking for a JAVA API which does the following. I've gone through apache commons arrayutils but couldn't find something useful.

The operation should be something of this type. Say the values range from 0 to 100.

I'd like to manipulate the array such that values less than 15 are changed to 15 and values greater than 70 are changed to 70.

Basically, I'm looking for an operation which would avoid me doing this - iterate through the array, check if the value is below 15, if it is below 15 then set it to 15 otherwise is it above 75, if it is above 75 then set the value to 75.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which language? And how else would you like to do it than comparing each element to the selected range?

Comment: Why exactly can't you loop over the array to do this?

Comment: Can't loop over because of the big array size. Also, this is image processing, and the range changes (15-75) very rapidly. I was hoping that there is an API somewhere which talks to Java Native and does the manipulation faster.

Comment: @RavSom: It's Java, not JAVA. There's no need to shout :)

Comment: oh sorry, didn't realize all caps was shouting. Duly apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there's some third-party library which has this functionality, it's just going to be doing exactly the same operation - looping over an array. Fundamentally you need something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = clamp(array[i], 15, 70);
}

...

public static byte clamp(byte value, byte min, byte max)
{
    return value < min ? min
         : value > max ? max
         : value;
}
```

You *could* implement this in native code if you really wanted, but I suspect you won't find an existing implementation. It's more likely that there are libraries which perform the sort of image manipulation you're interested in *as image manipulation* rather than as an array operation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Agreed, that is the primary objective. However, the speed of the operation is significant and if I do it this way that will be compromised considering the size of the array data(20MB)

Comment: @RavSom: But where are you executing this? Have you *tried* it to see whether the simple approach is fast enough?

Comment: @RavSom: I've just tried it, and on my laptop I can clamp a 20MB array in about 38ms (i.e. 1000 times in 38s). Is that fast enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Guava's [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) method to update the values. However, this would result in a new array not updating the values in the existing array.

```
List<Byte> list = Lists.newArrayList(myArray);
List<Byte> trans = Lists.transform(list, new Function<Byte, Byte>(){...});
byte[] bytes = Bytes.toArray(trans);
```

However, given what you are trying to do, I would suggest just looping over the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you write the simple loop, and profile it in the context of your application. **Only if you can demonstrate that this code is the overall bottleneck it would make sense to try and make it faster**.

I'd try something like this:

```
final int n = array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  int val = array[i];
  if (val < 15) {
    array[i] = 15;
  } else if (val > 75) {
    array[i] = 75;
  }
}
```

My final point is that this type of code is likely to be limited by memory bandwidth, so it seems unlikely that a native C solution  would be a lot faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the ranges like Jon skeet proposes, you could create a lookup table for each of the 256 possible a byte could have, i.e. something like

```
{15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,17,18,...,69,70,70,70,70,...}


for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    array[i] = lookup[array[i]];
}
```

In C: Less branching, much faster. In Java: Unfortunately not faster, even a bit slower, maybe because Java's array range checks eat up the speed gained; and since Java's bytes are always signed, it's a bit more complicated than shown above.

In C, you could even do that for 16bit halfwords, making it faster again. (Probably by factor 2)

EDIT: To my own shame, I must admit that proper testing revealed that the lookup table isn't faster in C. My first results were probably skewed by compiler optimisations. Anyway, at least on my machine,

```
if (array[i]<15) array[i]=15;
else if (array[i]>70) array[i]=70;
```

is noticable faster then using the ternary operator.